# Is there anythig incorrect when using placement new on global vars?

Tags: c++

I was playing with an idea where i can have variables in global scope but [not construct them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344346/how-do-i-cancel-not-call-the-constructor-in-a-global-variable/9344459#comment11795868_9344459). Note that there IS a placement new being ran. However i'd like to know what is undefined or incorrect about this code

```
#include <new>
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>

//#define AlignAs alignas(T)
#define AlignAs

template<class T>struct BlockOf {
    AlignAs char t[sizeof(T)];
    operator T&() { return reinterpret_cast<T&>(*this); }
    ~BlockOf(){((T*)&t)->~T(); }
};
struct B{ 
    virtual void v(){} 
    ~B() { printf("B\n"); } 
};
struct A: B{ 
    A(){printf("a\n");} 
    int regularDots; 
    void v() { printf("A virtual\n"); } 
};

BlockOf<A> _a;
A&a=_a;

void init(){
    new(&a) A;
}

int main() {
    init();
    A aa;
    a.regularDots=9;
    printf("%s %s %d %d\n", 
        typeid(a).name(),
        typeid(aa).name(),
        typeid(a).hash_code()==typeid(aa).hash_code(),
        sizeof(a) == sizeof(aa)
        );
    B *b = &a;
    b->v();
}
```

Comment: This isn't so bad, the code in your previous question just started accessing members, and *didn't* construct the object.

Comment: @BenVoigt: yep. It was a oversight. I wasn't planning to access members. I meant that as the syntax not use (oops).

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. You're trying to have global variables of a *forward declared* type. You want to stick the initializer and the storage in some other file, while you put the global reference somewhere else, all so that you don't have to `#include` the definition.

Comment: @acidzombie24: The more I see of your code, the more I think you should be using `boost::optional`.

Comment: (1) Alignment is wrong in compilers without `alignas` (2) `BlockOf` calls the destructor, even if contents are already destructed.  This is undefined behavior. (3) `~B` should be virtual, though the _potential_ undefined behavior does not come up in your code.

Comment: @MooingDuck: 3 is an oversight so your correct. 2 i believe you're incorrect because how would they be already destructed if theres no object (just the chuck of memory used with in place new and a reference). 1) yeah. I'm wondering if there is a standard predefined processor that says C++11 so i don't need to check the version of each compiler or manually defined a #define. Also is the place where it is used correct? i think so.

Comment: (2) by the same coin, you get undefined behavior if you call  `init()` more than once on accident. `__cplusplus` should be `201103` if it follows C++11, but every compiler does that, and none of them have all the features, so it's a useless flag.

Comment: You should put your `char` array into union with a type `T` variable, if you need proper alignment.

Comment: @qehgt: Putting T in a union doesn't compile

Answer (score 1):

This isn't clear

```
operator T&() { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(this); }
```

Instead use

```
operator T&() { return reinterpret_cast<T&>(t[0]); }
```

I think that `this` is required to point at the first member, but using the array explicitly seems safer to me.

---

To answer your main question, 3.8p8 contains the restrictions on reusing memory belonging to a variable with static storage duration, and since the original type has a trivial destructor, you should be ok.

> If a program ends the lifetime of an object of type `T` with static (3.7.1), thread (3.7.2), or automatic (3.7.3) storage duration and if `T` has a non-trivial destructor,
>   the program must ensure that an object of the original type occupies that same storage location when the implicit destructor call takes place; otherwise the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: It sounds like as long as i also call a inplace destructor i'm good for any use?

Comment: @acidzombie24: If you want the destructor called, you'll have to do it yourself.  Only you know whether the destructor does anything useful.

Comment: Theres no reason to not call it. I edited my code. Also is casting t[0] any different from `*this`? I don't see any reasons it may be safer

Comment: @acidzombie24: You applied an alignment restriction to `t`.  That should affect the alignment of the overall object, but using `t` is clearly, IMO.